# passing dropdown's selected value from view to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a dropdownlist in my asp.net MVC2 view like this:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("temp","Settings")){ %>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("drpFields", new SelectList(Model.Fields, "FieldID", "NiceName", whiteout.FieldID)) 
}
%>
```

and I want to pass the dropdown selected value from view to controller action. How do I modify this:

```
 <a class="icon-button-success" href='<%: Url.Action("EditWhiteOut", "Settings", new {FieldId = 1}) %>'>
     <img src='<%: Url.Content("~/static/Images/update.png") %>' alt="Update" />
 </a>
```

I want to pass dropdown's selected value to `FieldId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to use Ajax, you can avoid the form if you want to use `jQuery.ajax`. You might want to give your anchor a value for its ID property (my example below only uses its class attribute)

But, since you want to do a regular postback, you'll want to use another overload of `Html.BeginForm` so you can specify an ID attribute for the form (I specified the parameter names in case you're unfamiliar with this overload)

```
Html.BeginForm(actionName: "temp", controllerName: "Settings", 
    method: FormMethod.POST, htmlAttributes: new { id = "MyForm" })
```

And the jQuery used to make your link submit the form will create a standard submit. So, as long as your select list has a name attribute, it's value will be included in the post's payload.

```
$(function () {
    $('.icon-button-success').click(function (e) {
        $('#MyForm').submit();
        // you might not need preventDefault, but I can't remember if 
        // it will create a second post or not
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

If you wanted to do a redirect anyway (using the `$.ajax` method), you could always do `window.location.href='redirect/link';` inside the `success` function in the `$.ajax` call

Comment: I dont want to use ajax. I want to use html.beginform only. How can I do this with it ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow Ok, you should be able to get away with using `$.submit` on your form and binding a click function to the link you want to use to submit the form. I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

and what about 
this will trigger javascript submit of the form and provide button if js is not enabled

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(youraction)) {%>

<select name='myfield' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<option .... >
...
</select>
<noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
<%}%>
```

or using your code:
use jquery to update the value of the submit the value in which case
 javascript:

```
var link = Url.Action("EditWhiteOut", "Settings");
```

jquery

```
function toCallOnChange(){
 var linkParameter = $("#id of object").val();
 $("a.icon-button-success").attr("href", link+"\"+linkParameter ); //which will overwrite default value to current link
}


 <a class="icon-button-success" href='#'>
     <img src='<%: Url.Content("~/static/Images/update.png") %>' alt="Update" />
 </a>
```